# Grails Data Binding Failed for Date Field

Tags: json, grails, data-binding, request

I want to bind domain class with nested domain objects to request.JSON data. It works fine except for a field of type Date in nested domain class it always gives null. Here is request.json

```
[..., cardInfo:[expiryDate:2016-07-21, ccv:3455, cardNumber:4111111111111111], ....]
```

I tried to bind these json using multiple ways:

```
 MyClass myClass=new MyClass(request.JSON)
```

And

```
myClass.properties=request.JSON    
bindData(myClass,request.JSON)
bindData(myClass.cardInfo,request.JSON.cardInfo)
```

Nothing worked for binding expiryDate. Is this a bug or there is something wrong I'm doing?

UPDATE:

I'm using Grails 2.4.2 . I also have this line included in my config file

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['dd-MM-yyyy','MM-dd-yyyy','yyyy-MM-dd', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S']
```

Comment: What the exception you get?

Comment: Inspect `myClass.errors` after doing the binding.  That may indicate what is going wrong.

Comment: No exceptions. No errors this is from the log Binding Errors==>>grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors

Comment: Hi i am using grails 2.4. And i am getting below error:-                  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '1969-11-15T18:25:43.511Z' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information to know for sure but I expect that the binder isn't configured to know about your date format.  You can try something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    @org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
    Date expiryDate
}
```

You can also configure that as a default date format in Config.groovy:

```
// grails-app/conf/Config.groovy
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['yyyy-MM-dd', 'MMddyyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"]
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding for more details.

I hope that helps.

Comment: You didn't indicate which version of Grails you are using.  I should have mentioned that the `BindingFormat` annotation I mentioned above was introduced in Grails 2.3 along with the then new data binder.  If you are using an older version, the same sort of problem may be happening but the solution would be different.

Comment: I 'm using Grails 2.4.2. I tried your second suggestion before but this doesn't work for me. It seems like the second one didn't work also

Comment: Hi i am using grails 2.4. And i am getting below error:-                  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '1969-11-15T18:25:43.511Z' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems here:

1. Your JSON should have the date value in quotes (i.e. expiryDate: "2016-07-21").  Without quotes, it's probably binding only the beginning numeric part (2016), which is not one of your configured formats.
2. There appears to be a Grails bug (we're on 2.5.0) with binding dates in nested domain classes (which is why I'm here).  If you bind it properly (meaning, the date's format matches a format defined in grails.databinding.dateFormats), the date attribute is set fine.  However, if there's a mismatch (meaning, the value is "2016" but the config is 'yyyy-MM-dd', the bad value is silently discarded without a validation error.  I've seen this behavior with both embedded nested classes and in a belongsTo relationship, and I think that's why your expiryDate remains null.

Comment: Hi i am using grails 2.4. And i am getting below error:-                  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '1969-11-15T18:25:43.511Z' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'